# Get id from URL but database results aren't shown

Tags: php, sql

I use the following:

```
<a href="showlog.php?id=<?php echo $car['car_id']; ?>">
```

and I get a url that looks like this:

> https://example.com/showlog.php?id=AAA1111

So now in the `showlog.php` file I want select from a table all the lines that have this id value saved as `car_id` and echo the `id` (primary key which is different than the `car_id`), the `trn_date`, and the `kilometers`, so I use the following code:

```
<?php
include 'main.php';
checkLoggedIn($pdo);
$id=$_GET['id'];
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id, trn_date, kilometers FROM serv WHERE car_id = '.$id.' ');
$stmt->execute([$_SESSION['id']]);
$cars = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body class="loggedin">
        <div class="content">
            <h2>Ser</h2>
            <div>
                <table> 
                <?php foreach($cars as $car): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="showser.php?id=<?php echo "". $car["id"]. ""; ?>" style="color:DarkCyan; text-decoration: none">
                                <img src="images/car_service.png" width="40" height="40"> Date: <?="". $car["trn_date"]. ""?>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td>kilometers: <?="". $car["kilometers"]. ""?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><th colspan="8"><br/><hr width="100%"></th><tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The page loads but I get nothing as result. What am I doing wrong? :/

Comment: Do you want to execute the query with `$_SESSION['id']` or `$_GET['id']`? You seem to be binding to a query that doesn't include any parameters.

Comment: Do you `session_start()`? By the way, you should use `$stmt->bindParam`.

Comment: I made it work by change it all! I guess I was confused a lot! Thank you both!